# Why does crontab -e not work on Raspberry Pi 3b

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, cron-task

I am struggling since a couple of days to make a python script run whenever the pi reboots using crontab. I have used quiet a number of solutions but the job doesn't run at reboot.

I have tried

```
@reboot python3 /home/pi/Desktop/my_test.py.
```

I have also tried a few other fixes like giving full path of python, delaying the start of the file but nothing seems to work. Is there a bug or am I missing something?

Please help me out guys

Comment: Is your question about using the `crontab -e` command to edit the crontab file, or about what to put into the crontab file? Either way, this isn't really a programming question, it's a Unix configuration question. Unix.stackexchange.com or SuperUser.com would be better places to ask.

Comment: When you use `crontab -l`, does it show what you added with `crontab -e`? If so, then `crontab -e` did work.

Comment: Maybe the version of `cron` you're running doesn't support `@reboot`. If you want to run something at reboot, shouldn't it be in `/etc/init.d`?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a dot after `.py`?

Comment: Hi guys..thanks for replying. The "." Is there by mistake. Doing crontab -l shows the @reboot line. To test the crontab running, I have a test python script that saves a plot on the desktop. When I boot, nothing shows up on the desktop. While running the same script via the terminal saves a figure on the desktop.

Comment: maybe you need `/full/path/to/python3 /home/pi/...` ? If that works, then check `man cron` and see if your version supports a first line in `crontab -e` like `PATH=/path/to/python:/usr/bin/:usr/sbin/:...` Good luck.

Comment: Change that crontab line to `@reboot python3 /home/pi/Desktop/my_test.py >>/tmp/log 2>&1` and see if any errors appear in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the question, but in the end I added my script in /etc/rc.local instead of cron. I think there are too many bugs in cron.

With the following:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
```